# Send data from fragment to another when we use dependency injection for fragments

Tags: android, kotlin, fragment, bundle, koin

**Is there a way for sending data from a `fragment` to another without create new `instance` from it ?**

**I `inject` my `fragment` but i faced with a problem that i describe it in below :**

**We `inject` our `fragments` like this :**

```
val fragmentModule= module {

    factory { MyFragment() }
}
```

**And this is a `function` for replace `fragment` :**

```
fun AppCompatActivity.replaceFragment(fragment: Class<out Fragment>,frameId: Int){

    supportFragmentManager
        .beginTransaction()
        .replace(frameId,fragment,null,null)
        .commit()
}
```

**Then i use it like this :**

```
activity.replaceFragment(MyFragment::class.java,R.id.frameLayoutId)
```

**So my question is how can i set `argument` to `fragment` in this way and without create new `instance` of `fragment` how can we pass a data ?**

```
    val bundle=Bundle()
    bundle.putString("YourKey","YourData")
    val fragment=MyFragment()
    fragment.arguments=bundle
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`without create new instance?` NO . Dependency injection framework only takes care of provide the dependencies where needed it does not connect the Component automatically in  any way.

With `Koin` you can pass the `Bundle` during creation of fragment using a `FragmentFactory`.

```
val arguments = Bundle().apply { 
putString("key", "value")
}
supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
.replace(R.id.container, MyFragment::class.java, arguments)
.commit()
```

To pass data after the fragment created you have set it in `Fragment` somehow. There can be following options:-

1. If you are using `MVVM` you can use a shared `ViewModel` to pass the data using `LiveData`.
2. Alternatively you can get the `Fragment` from back stack and call a method on it.
3. Or you can use a callback interface

Comment: I found this https://github.com/InsertKoinIO/koin/blob/master/koin-projects/docs/reference/koin-android/fragment-factory.md now , any way thanks for your answer and about this `without create new instance?` my mean was directly.